# ListView elements not clickable with mouse

Tags: java, listview, javafx, fxml

I made a ListView but when I try to select an item from it with the mouse it doesn't works. The only way to select the item is by using the arrows on keyboard. This is my fxml:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mailbox.ListController">
<ListView fx:id="listView" layoutY="29.0" mouseTransparent="false" prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="240.0" /></AnchorPane>
```

This is the Controller of the list:

```
public class ListController {
@FXML
private ListView<Email> listView ;
private DataModel model ;

public void initModel(DataModel model) {
    if (this.model != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
    }
    this.model = model ;
    model.loadData(null);
    listView.setItems(model.getEmailList());   
    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> 
        model.setCurrentEmail(newSelection));

    model.currentEmailProperty().addListener((obs, oldEmail, newEmail) -> {
        if (newEmail == null) {
            listView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        } else {
            listView.getSelectionModel().select(newEmail);
        }
    });

    listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Email>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Email mail, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(mail, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(mail.getMittente());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And this is where I declare it:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader listLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("lista.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader textareaLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("textarea.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader fieldLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("textfield.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader menuLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("menubar.fxml"));

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(listLoader.load(), textareaLoader.load(), fieldLoader.load(), menuLoader.load());

    ListController listController = listLoader.getController();
    TextAreaController textareaController = textareaLoader.getController();
    TextFieldController fieldController = fieldLoader.getController();
    MenuBarController menuController = menuLoader.getController();
```

Comment: Is your `currentEmailProperty()` adding a listener within the `listView`'s listener? If so, this needs to be pulled out.

Comment: No, it simply return an ObjectProperty<Email> instance.

Comment: Let me be more clear. The listener added to the `listView`'s `selectedItemProperty()` ALSO has it adding a listener to the `model.currentEmailProperty()`. This means everytime an item changes, a new listener is added to the `currentEmailProperty()`, which is not something you want. Move that piece of code out and then retest.

Comment: Nothing changed, when I try to click on an element of the list it doesn't get selected.